# PostgreSQL in Azure - display SQL queries results as part of dashboard

Tags: postgresql, azure, performance, monitor

I have few instances of Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers. I would like that as I display the system health metrics in a dashboard, I will be also able to query data from the DB server and display it in the dashboard every x time.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It's just a database. Connect to it & run queries. I'm not sure I completely understand the question.

Comment: ok, but how can I make the result of the query be displayed in the dashboard?

Comment: Which dashboard? Where? You've got to clarify the question to get good answers.